# Kinect SDK v1 samples in VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, kinect

Does anyone know where I can find examples of the new Kinect SDK in VB and more specific a port of the KinectExplorer sample?

I have ported the whole WPFViewers Project in VB [here](http://wtrns.fr/s4qf1Cio1s7J4cI), but it has errors on the XAML.

Answer (score 0):

One of the nice things about the .net framework and all other CLR languages is that you can translate between then very easily.

http://www.developerfusion.com/tools/convert/csharp-to-vb/

Just copy the code that you want in VB in here and it will translate it.

Example translation of the KinectWindow.cs file:

```
'------------------------------------------------------------------------------
' <copyright file="KinectWindow.cs" company="Microsoft">
'     Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.
' </copyright>
'------------------------------------------------------------------------------

Imports System.Windows
Imports Microsoft.Kinect
Imports Microsoft.Samples.Kinect.WpfViewers
Namespace Microsoft.Samples.Kinect.KinectExplorer

    ''' <summary>
    ''' This is the core kinect window.
    ''' </summary>
    Public Class KinectWindow
        Inherits Window
        #Region "Private state"
        Private ReadOnly kinectDiagnosticViewer As KinectDiagnosticViewer
        Private m_kinect As KinectSensor
        #End Region

        Public Sub New()
            Me.kinectDiagnosticViewer = New KinectDiagnosticViewer()
            Me.kinectDiagnosticViewer.KinectColorViewer.CollectFrameRate = True
            Me.kinectDiagnosticViewer.KinectDepthViewer.CollectFrameRate = True
            Content = Me.kinectDiagnosticViewer
            Width = 1024
            Height = 600
            Title = "Kinect Explorer"
            AddHandler Me.Closed, AddressOf Me.KinectWindowClosed
        End Sub

        Public Property Kinect() As KinectSensor
            Get
                Return Me.m_kinect
            End Get

            Set
                Me.m_kinect = value
                Me.kinectDiagnosticViewer.Kinect = Me.m_kinect
            End Set
        End Property

        Public Sub StatusChanged()
            Me.kinectDiagnosticViewer.StatusChanged()
        End Sub

        Private Sub KinectWindowClosed(sender As Object, e As System.EventArgs)
            ' KinectDiagnosticViewer will call kinectSensor.Stop() so we properly release its use.
            Me.Kinect = Nothing
        End Sub
    End Class
End Namespace
```

And as for the XAML:

```
<kv:ImageViewer x:Class="TC.Samples.Kinect.WpfViewers.KinectSkeletonViewer"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
             xmlns:kv="clr-namespace:TC.Samples.Kinect.WpfViewers.TC.Samples.Kinect.WpfViewers"
             d:DesignHeight="480" d:DesignWidth="640">
    <Grid>
        <kv:KinectSkeleton x:Name="skeletonCanvas1" ClipToBounds="true">
        </kv:KinectSkeleton>
        <kv:KinectSkeleton x:Name="skeletonCanvas2" ClipToBounds="true">
        </kv:KinectSkeleton>
        <kv:KinectSkeleton x:Name="skeletonCanvas3" ClipToBounds="true">
        </kv:KinectSkeleton>
        <kv:KinectSkeleton x:Name="skeletonCanvas4" ClipToBounds="true">
        </kv:KinectSkeleton>
        <kv:KinectSkeleton x:Name="skeletonCanvas5" ClipToBounds="true">
        </kv:KinectSkeleton>
        <kv:KinectSkeleton x:Name="skeletonCanvas6" ClipToBounds="true">
        </kv:KinectSkeleton>
    </Grid>
</kv:ImageViewer>
```

Comment: Ah, so that's the XAML.  Could you update your post with the code from the XAML file?  I'll change the namespace so that it will compile :)  Also, make sure that all your References are working properly

Comment: Joe, I have translated the whole project, but I get the error on KinectSkeletonViewer.xaml :



Error 8 The tag ImageViewer does not exist in XML namespace clr-namespace:Microsoft.Samples.Kinect.WpfViewers.

Comment: I am afraid it gives the same error. Did you load the WPFViewers project I uploaded?

Comment: Yes.  It's the `xmlns:kv="clr-namespace:TC.Samples.Kinect.WpfViewers.TC.Samples.Kinect.WpfViewers"` that's giving you trouble.  I was able to load it up and get everything installed and working.  Everything came up for me...

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/8137/discussion-between-joe-coolish-and-abinop)